# Is it ok to use a non-id pointer as value in objc_SetAssociatedObject?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

As the title says. Nothing goes wrong immediately if I do this:

```
- (void) associateSelector:(SEL)value withPointer:(void*)key
{
    objc_SetAssociatedObject(self, key, (id) value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}
```

Are there any good reasons to be cautious about using it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the API in a way not explicitly supported by the document. So, you can't complain when it breaks in the next update of OS X / iOS. That's one reason to be cautious about.

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) says that `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASIGN` sets up a weak reference. This means a nontrivial thing in the garbage-collected situation, so beware.

If there's a way to do things in an officially supported way, I would prefer it. In your case, using `NSStringFromSelector` would immediately make your code supported.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea. As Yuji says, you're violating the API as defined in the documentation. If you really want to store arbitrary values, wrap then in `NSValue` and store that as an `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.

```
- (void) associateSelector:(SEL)value withPointer:(void*)key {
    NSValue *nsvalue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&value objcType:@encode(SEL)];
    objc_SetAssociatedObject(self, key, nsvalue, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```